# How to read first line of multiple .txt files in the same folder and write into another .txt file in R?

Tags: r

**I have 30 .txt files in a tabular format and I want to take the first row of each (as well as the second, and third...etc. eventually) and write them into their own respective .txt files.**

An example end product would be a .txt file containing all the first rows of data from the 30 .txt files.

These files are in a working directory and would like to call these files directly from there.

I have implemented the following loop... While I get the rows that I desire, I also get a bunch of undesired [1]'s in the output.

```
direc <- setwd("the path of my files")  
files <- list.files("the path of my files")
num_files <- length(files)

line <- list()

for (i in 1:num_files) {
  line <- list(line, read.table(files[[i]], header = F, nrows = 1))
}

print(line)
```

Comment: Do they all have the same columns? Does the order of the rows in the new file matter?

Comment: And do they have the same number of rows?

Comment: Yes, each txt file has the same numbers of rows and columns (10 rows and 12 columns).
The row order is the same for all of them (they all containing the same corresponding data)

Answer (score 2):

I will presume your files have header and secondary lines only for this MRE, and that each file has the same number of lines. This first chunk of code simulates your data with these assumptions. The second chunk will be your solution. The solution will work for a finite number of lines.

```
# packages
install.packages('pacman')
library(pacman)
p_load(magrittr, purrr, tibble, dplyr, tidyr, readr)


# MRE setup (simulate files).
x <- paste0('sample_', seq(1:3), '.txt')
map(x, file.create)

y <- tibble::tibble(
  file_number = seq(1:3),
  files = list.files(pattern = '.txt', full.names = T)
)


y %$%
  # write header to each file for MRE.
  walk2(files, file_number,
               ~write_lines(x = paste0('my_header', .y), file = .x, append = F))

y %$%
  # write second line to each file for MRE.
  walk2(files, file_number,
               ~write_lines(x = paste0('my_secondary', .y), file = .x, append = T))
```

```
# your great code.

# number of lines in every file.
number_of_lines <- 2
number_of_files <- 3



# flag lines with line number.
filter_condition <- seq(1:number_of_lines) %>%
  # my_flag_here will eventually become a file name.
  paste('my_flag_here', sep = '_', .) %>%
  # repeat the sequence of line numbers for
  # as many files as there are.
  rep(times = number_of_files)


# load file contents into tibble data structure.
my_file_tibble <- tibble(
  my_file_list = list.files(pattern = '.txt', full.names = T),
  my_file_contents = map(my_file_list, read_tsv, col_names = F)
)


# now let's do some rearranging.
my_rearrange <- my_file_tibble %>%
  # remove old file names.
  select(-my_file_list) %>%
  # expand the columns.
  unnest(my_file_contents) %>%
  # map the lines to line numbers.
  mutate(
    filter_on = filter_condition
  )

# now the lines are flagged with the line numbers
# and a flag of your choosing.
my_next_rearrange <- my_rearrange %>%
  # create groupings for which line number
  # the line appears on.
  group_by(filter_on) %>%
  nest() %>%
  # coerce new file name.
  mutate(
    filter_on = paste0(filter_on, '.txt')
  )



# now write the new contents to files.
my_next_rearrange %$%
  walk2(data, filter_on, write_tsv, col_names = F)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am taking a class for R right now where only the basics are used, so a lot of this is over my head.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't worry about how I re-create your data so much as the other parts. The dplyr, magrittr, and tidyr packages are super versatile. Try going by the code line by line, and even break down individual statements. I try to avoid using R like I would Python (avoiding for loops usually).